# Detection methods for Nickell bias in Stata?

Tags: stata, panel-data

I have dynamic panel data and quite a huge gap between the fixed effect estimator and the pooled OLS estimator, which lets me conclude I could suffer from a Nickell-Bias. That is, my lagged explanatory variable is correlated with the error term.

However, I do not know how I can test for the "Nickell-bias" in Stata? Is there any clear test that can be of any help?

Thank you!